# Multiple Info.plist files in MonoTouch solution

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, info-plist

I'm trying to write two separate submittable apps: one for iPad and the other for iPhone. This necessitates having two separate plists to allow independently specifying different app icons, launch images, etc.

When I try to rename my Info.plist, MonoDevelop autocreates a new empty Info.plist and uses that instead. By the same token, I can't seem to move my Info.plist to the iPad/ subfolder and have MD pick it up there.

Currently we have 3 projects in 1 solution: iPad, iPhone, common files and libraries.

Is the only solution to have separate .sln files in the appropriate subfolders, or can I still somehow build two separate apps from one .sln?

*EDIT:* Project structure is below if that helps visualise the problem.

```
MyApp.sln
MyApp-iPad.csproj
MyApp-iPhone.csproj
MyApp-Common.csproj

Main.cs
AppDelegate-iPad.cs
AppDelegate-iPhone.cs

Info.plist (MD currently uses this for both projects)
Common/
iPad/
iPad/Info.plist (for -iPad.csproj)
iPhone/
iPhone/Info.plist (for -iPhone.csproj)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's my current and very ordinary solution: Add a custom command that runs Before Build

```
cp iPad/Info.plist Info.plist
```

And for iPhone:

```
cp iPhone/Info.plist Info.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a project where I need to be able to build the application with different icons and resources.

I use different build profiles and build scripts that copy in the correct files into a resources folder. This also changes the application name and identifier.

This is a similar solution to yours, but it would allow you to bundle different images with your application like you wanted.

Comment: does this work in Xamarin? when I modify the bundle I mess up the code signing, so that the app only runs when using the debug configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 2 projects, one for iPad and one for iPhone.

You should "link-in" all the code files from one project to the other.  You can have different Info.plist files, icons, images, etc. with this route.

Here is a link talking about various strategies: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Application_Fundamentals/Building_Cross_Platform_Applications/Sharing_Code_Options

Comment: +1 helpful link, but I don't think your suggestion works for this project structure. We already have a library project with common files; this is just talking about the application-level plist for iPad vs iPhone. It looks like MD forces you to use the `Info.plist` file on the same level as the `.sln`. We have made 2 *projects*, but did you mean I need to make 2 *solutions*?

Comment: Make 2 application level projects (doesn't matter what your existing structure is), YourAppiPhone and YourAppiPad.  Link in any shared files from YourAppiPhone in YourAppiPad such as `Main.cs` or `AppDelegate.cs`.  You won't need 2 solutions.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but we've already done that and the issue is that MD still wants both application-level projects to use `Info.plist` in the same folder as the `.sln`..

Comment: They should be in subdirectories from your main sln.  Are you trying to put both of these csproj files in the same directory?  I will put an example on Github if I have a chance today.